# Boost tribool causing right to left conditional evaluation in C++

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, conditional-statements, operator-precedence

To my knowledge, C++ always evaluates from left to right in a conditional statement

```
if(A, B, C)
```

`A` would be evaluated first, `B` second, so on.  However, the following example is exhibiting some odd behavior.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/logic/tribool.hpp>

//-////////////////////////////////////////////
// File Block
class FileBlock {
public:
    FileBlock();
    virtual ~FileBlock();
    bool linked();

    std::vector<int> messages_;

private:
    boost::logic::tribool position_;
    std::shared_ptr<FileBlock> precedingBlock_ = nullptr;
    std::shared_ptr<FileBlock> followingBlock_ = nullptr;
};

FileBlock::FileBlock()  {
    std::cout << "Breakpoint." << std::endl;

    // "linked()" evaluated first by scope.
    if(linked())    {
        if(!position_
            && precedingBlock_->messages_.back() > 1)   {
                std::cout << "Unreachable." << std::endl;
        }
    }

    // "linked()" evaluated first without the tribool.
    if(linked()
        && precedingBlock_->messages_.back() > 1)   {
            std::cout << "Unreachable." << std::endl;
    }

    // "precedingBlock_->messages_.back() > 1" evaluated first. (Crash because null.)
    if(linked()
        && !position_
        && precedingBlock_->messages_.back() > 1)   {
            std::cout << "Unreachable." << std::endl;
    }
}

FileBlock::~FileBlock() {}

bool FileBlock::linked()    {
    return false;
}

//-////////////////////////////////////////////
// main
int main()  {
    std::shared_ptr<FileBlock> followingBlock(new FileBlock());

    return 0;
}
```

There are three versions of the conditional in the example.  To my knowledge, the first and last should evaluate the same.  However, as I trace the program in gdb, when I reach the third version of the conditional, the *right most* condition is the first to be evaluated.

Scoping the conditional obviously fixes the issue (as demonstrated in the first version of the conditional), as does removing the tribool altogether as demonstrated in the second conditional, but I **should** be able to use the third one without incident!

The program should kick out and return without doing anything since the left most condition is always false, but this is not the case.

What is up here?  Am I not understanding something about tribool?  Am I *hallucinating*?

Here's a inventory of the mingw build I'm using as well as the installed libraries:

```
Core Inventory:
 - autoconf2.5-2.68-1
 - autoconf-10-1
 - automake1.11-1.11.1-1
 - binutils-2.24-1
 - expat-2.1.0-1
 - gcc-c++-4.8.1-4
 - gcc-core-4.8.1-4
 - gdb-7.6.1-1
 - gettext-0.18.3.1-1
 - gmp-5.1.2-1
 - libiconv-1.14-3
 - libltdl-2.4-1
 - libtool-2.4-1
 - make-3.82.90-2
 - mingwrt-4.0.3-1
 - mpc-1.0.1-2
 - mpfr-3.1.2-2
 - pthreads-w32-2.9.1-1
 - w32api-4.0.3-1
 - wsl_rc-4.0-1
 - zlib-1.2.8-1

Auxiliary Inventory:
 - wxWidgets 3.0.0
 - Boost 1.55
 - yaml-cpp 0.5.1
```

Here are my build commands:

```
g++ -std=gnu++11 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\main.o" "..\\src\\main.cpp" 
g++ -o wtf.exe "src\\main.o"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unlike built-in logical operators, overloaded logical operators (and [they *are* overloaded for `boost::tribool`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/tribool/reference.html#header.boost.logic.tribool_hpp)) don't have left-to-right order of evaluation (nor short-circuit semantics). The order of evaluation of operands is unspecified like almost everywhere else.

Comment: Now that we have lambda, we should push for short-circuit based overloading options on `&&`.  Something like `template<typename RHS> tribool operator&&( tribool b, RHS&& rhs, int )` if we want to go the `++` route, or we could use other syntax to indicate "alternative overload semantics" that doesn't suck (suggestions?).  Then the `rhs` would be a `lambda` implicitly created by the language (with `[&]` capture) of the right-hand-side of the `&&` clause.  Within the `&&` overload we could choose to evaluate it (with `()`) or not, thus allowing short-circuit style logic.

Comment: Is there a reason why an overloaded logical operator doesn't get left-to-right order of evaluation, while a member function does?

Comment: @Präriewolf Member function doesn't either!

Comment: @jrok So there is no guarantee that the second conditional will always check in that order?

Comment: Left-to-right order is guaranteed by **1)** built-in logical operators (`&&`, `||`), **2)** conditional operator ( operand to the left of `?` first, then one of the remaining ones), **3)** built-in comma operator, **4)** inside braced initializer list (`{ }`). And I think that covers everything. Everywhere else, the order is unspecified.

Comment: @Yakk: how would you short circuit on a single tribool? anyways, wrong place to discuss, maybe the standard c++ mailing list is.

Comment: @jrok: built-in comma operator.

Comment: @PlasmaHH agreed.  But if the tribool was `false`, you would not have to evaluate the RHS and simply return.  If it was `maybe` or `true`, you would have to.  The point is that we have native efficient objects that represent "later execution" in the language now, so we *could* implement short-circuit now.

Comment: @jrok Sorry, I'm being dense today.  So let me make sure I understand. Since I use && in the second conditional, and there is no overload or the logical operator, then those will evaluate in order.  However, since tribool overloaded &&, that caused me to lose any guarantee of order?